# View [login] not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel project and I added a link to log out in my sidebar

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Se déconnecter') }}
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ ('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
```

but Once I click on the link I get **View [login] not found.**

can you help ?

**Update**
[image]

**update 2**

I put the logout link in the view of my sidebar

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">

        <li>
            <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> After sales & Parts<span class="fa arrow fa-fw"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Obeya</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Parts</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-usd fa-fw"></i> Finances</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-lg fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Paramétrages</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a  href="{{ route('logout') }}"
               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>
                {{ __('Se déconnecter') }}
            </a>

            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                @csrf
            </form>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
<!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Do you have the login view in your `resources/views` directory?

Comment: Yes I do! under `resources/views/auth`

Comment: Can you show the output of `php artisan route:list` in your question?

Comment: @Tanmay updated !

Comment: Why you have slash in {{//route}}

Comment: @LimKeanPhang it's just because I was putting that portion of code under comment I forget to take it off when I post it here, Sorry!

Comment: @M_M checkout my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed `route` function in your form!

You should change:

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ ('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```

to

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```

For more details check [Auth Code](https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/partials/nav.blade.php)

**UPDATE:**

OP was redirecting to `login` view after `logout` but OP didn't called the view correctly in his routes.

In OP web.php the return code was like:

`return view('login');`

So after changing the above code to below it started working

`return view('auth.login');`

Because when we run `php artisan make:auth`, the login and other files are inside auth directory!

Comment: Still the same error? Can you share your controller code?

Comment: The one responsible for login and logout!

Comment: You generated auth via `php artisan make:auth` right? or is it custom?

Comment: Also share the full veiw code so that I can see what's going on!

Comment: Yes I generated the auth but then I customized the view and changed the location of the logout link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187807/discussion-between-iftikhar-uddin-and-m-m).

Answer (score 0):

you have to name your route  as "login" 
example

```
Route::get('/userlogin',['as'=>'login','uses'=>'yourcontroller@yourmethod']);
```

or

```
Route::get('/userlogin', function () {
    //
})->name('login');
```

Comment: should i add another view userlogin ?

Comment: no need just name the route that refer to your login  view

Comment: I've just name the view that refer to my login but still not working

Comment: still having "View [login] not found" or message changed